# The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application thrown when using `GetConversationItems`

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchangewebservices

In my outlook web add-in I use Office.js's `getCallbackTokenAsync`
 to get the token before connecting to `EWS` in my asp.net back end.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
                service.Url = new Uri(mailItem.ewsUrl);
                service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(mailItem.ewsToken);
                PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(
                                                ItemSchema.Subject,
                                                );
                _email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(mailItem.itemID),ps);
//the following throws error
    ConversationResponse response = service.GetConversationItems(convId,
                                                                 properties,
                                                                 null,
                                                                 foldersToIgnore,
                                                                 ConversationSortOrder.TreeOrderDescending);
```

Seems like this `GetConversationItems` method is not allowed when I used the token retrieved by Office.js to initialize the EWS service. I tried to updated the manifest permission to the highest level to `ReadWriteMailBox` but still not working. Seems like I can only use Office.js to call `EWS`?

Comment: I have same issue when I try to use the ConvertId operation, did you ever find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 3):

The token you get from getCallbackTokenAsync is only used to retrieve attachments on the current item or on the current item.
For more information, please see the following link:

[getCallbackTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5&view=office-js#getcallbacktokenasynccallback-usercontext)

Best Regards,

Evan

Comment: Is there any workaround then? I just want to use the `GetConversationItems` in the back end of my office web add-in. Seems to me that I need to use the traditional name and password authorisation to do that.

Comment: You can try to get the identity token using getUserIdentityTokenAsync() to initialize the EWS service. For more information, please see the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token

Comment: I tried, I used the token returned by `getUserIdentityTokenAsync()` to init the EWS service,and I still canot use `GetConversationItems`

Comment: Has your server been successfully initialized?
Is this server an Exchange version starting with Exchange Server 2013?

Comment: I am testing on my company's office 365. So I guess it would be exchange online? Do you know how to detect the exchange version in run time?